# How to populate many-to-many table from two others on a string column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am familiar with SQL but haven't used it enough and I am completely new to PostgreSQL.

My problem is that I have two tables, one of which has a column with a string values that contains indices referencing other table, these are joined in a string, and I want to generate a third table that would have indices for many-to-many relation.

**Table 1:**

```
tags: {
    id: bigint,
    tag: character varying(10),
    connected: character varying(10),
    meaning: character varying(120),
    CONSTRAINT: tags_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
}
```

**Table 2:**

```
words: {
    id: bigint,
    form: character varying(255),
    lemmas: character varying(255),
    original: character varying(255),
    tsv_form_text: tsvector,
    CONSTRAINT words_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
}
```

These are not actually SQL but should give you the idea of the tables.

The `words.lemmas` contains something like: `noun:p:m`, where each part splitter by `:` is a unique `tags.tag` name.

I want to split this `lemmas` column and then for each tag name find the tag `id` and write a row into many-to-many table with `word.id` and `tags.id`.

Could someone give me any suggestions on how to achieve this?

I have tried writing FOR LOOP in a SQL Console in pgAdmin, but it says `incorrect syntax near FOR. I have no idea how to do this with SELECT

**UPDATE**

Dummy code I was trying to do but still could not get it running:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dummy_function()
RETURNS TABLE 
(
    word_id bigint,
    tag_id bigint
)
AS $$
DECLARE
    WORD_ID bigint;
    LEMMAS varchar(255)[];
    TAG_ID bigint;
BEGIN
    FOREACH word IN words LOOP
        LEMMAS = string_to_array(QuestionList_, ':')

        FOREACH lemma in ARRAY LEMMAS LOOP
        -- HERE I want to return word_id and tag_id that I would later insert into relations table
            RETURN QUERY word.id, SELECT tags.id FROM tags WHERE tag = lemma
        END LOOP
    END LOOP
    RETURN
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: @Andreas updated the question, this is what I am trying to do now, it was not working `FOREACH word IN words LOOP` where `words` is a table

Comment: well if you got incorrect syntax, you should check the syntax rule for that language

Comment: @Andreas Could you also tell me if this function actually makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`unnest(string_to_array(..))`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) is handy and rather fast. Demo

```
with words(id, lemmas) as (
  values 
     (1, 'as:df:gh')
    ,(2, 'zx:cv:bn')
), tags(id, tag) as (
  values 
     (11, 'as')
    ,(12, 'df')
    ,(13, 'gh')
    ,(14, 'zx')
    ,(15, 'cv')
    ,(16, 'bn')
)
select w.id wordId, t.id tagId
from (
   select id, unnest(string_to_array(lemmas, E':')) word
   from words
) w
join tags t on t.tag = w.word;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=a3befc41e1d2c8f4caae762f52fe7df3)

Comment: This made it a bit a bit quicker and easier to read. And also to add, some of the syntax problems in my approach were the `;` after expressions that I missed)